# Asp.Net Core Connection with Oracle Database using TCPS Not workinf

Tags: asp.net, oracle, asp.net-core

I am trying to establish connection with oracle databse using asp.net core with TCPS protocol.
When i open connection it gives me execption
**Network Transport : SSL failure in parsing wallet location
TCPS : invalid SSL wallet (Magic version)**

Note:
When i try to connect databes using same wallet location with TOD oracle it sucessfully connected. but not connecting with.net core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resloved this issue.

Problem is i was trying to read ssl certificate using direct path
i.e OracleConfiguration.WalletLocation = "C:\app\oracle\wallet". .net is unalbe to read this.

**Solution**
I add my certificate in **windows certificate store** then i changed my wallet location to
OracleConfiguration.WalletLocation = "(SOURCE = (METHOD = MCS))";

Then it works